# Get the actual type from a Type variable

Tags: c#, generics, typeof

I am trying to get a type from a Type variable. For example:

```
Type t = typeof(String);
var result = SomeGenericMethod<t>();
```

An error happens on the second line, because `t` is not a `type`, it's a variable. Any way to make it a type?

Comment: Why can't you do `SomeGenericMethod<String>()`, if this is not your use case then you need to provide how you are actually going to use it because the best way to solve it depends on how you are doing it. Assuming `var` will be the type of `t` then what you really want is `t result = ...` which is a whole diffrent problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that seems like an example... for the sake of example. Cyan, please state if it is or not.

Comment: I get the type as a parameter in a method and then I want to pass it to the generic method. Yes, it's just an example.

Comment: @Mafii An example that's not nearly representative enough to be helpful. The answer here *could* be to use a type alias instead of a variable: `using t = System.String;`. The answer here *could* be that it's fundamentally impossible. It depends on details that are not present in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot know the value of a `Type` object at compile time, which is what you would need to do in order to use a `Type` object as an actual type.  Whatever you're doing that needs to use that `Type` will need to do so dynamically, and not require having a type known at compile time.

Comment: Point is, generic type arguments have to be known at compile time. +1

Comment: They need to be known at compile time because they are compile time protection, not because they are intrinsic to the compilation process. Generics being checked at compile is a (life-saving) safety thing, not a pure requirement.

Answer (score 7):

To make an instance of a generic based on a Type, you can use reflection to get an instance of the generic with the type you want to use, then use Activator to create that instance:

```
Type t = typeof (string); //the type within our generic

//the type of the generic, without type arguments
Type listType = typeof (List<>); 

//the type of the generic with the type arguments added
Type generictype = listType.MakeGenericType(t); 

//creates an instance of the generic with the type arguments.
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(generictype);
```

Note that `x` here will be an `object`. To call functions on it, such as `.Sort()`, you'd have to make it a `dynamic`.

**Please Note** that this code is hard to read, write, maintain, reason about, understand, or love. If you have *any* alternatives to needing to use this sort of structure, explore those *thoroughly*.

**Edit**: You can also cast the object you receive from the `Activator`, such as `(IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType)`. This will give you some functionality without having to resort to dynamics.

Comment: @lokusking I'm not sure what you're trying to say, though I did notice that link talks about casting the object you receive back from the Activator instance. I will update my answer regarding that.

Comment: Its not about creating instances but invoking generic methods

Comment: @lokusking Actually the question asks how to use a `Type` as a type, which is neither.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly workaround using reflection:

**Class with generic Method**

```
public class Dummy {
        public string WhatEver<T>() {
            return "Hello";
        }    
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 var d = new Dummy();
 Type t = typeof(string);
 var result = typeof(Dummy).GetMethod("WhatEver").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(d, null);
```

On class instantiation see Max's solution